# Decompress/decode ASCII-encoded PNG bytes to NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, png, nsdata, compression

I receive some data over a websocket. The data is ASCII-encoded PNG bytes. I need to decompress the PNG bytes to a readable NSString. The PNG bytes contains json data and hence not an image, PNG has just been used for compression.

Where I am right now is that I have used the following to get the ASCII encoded data, which I believe is correct. dataReceivedViaWebsocket is a NSString.

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:dataReceivedViaWebsocket options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

This yields the following for decodedString, it at least looks like it is correct since the PNG is in the header.

```
\U00000089PNG\r\n\x1a\n
```

Now I just need to decompress/decode the PNG data to a NSString, but cannot figure out how to do it.

**Edit: Found an implementation in Javascript. Is this even possible in Objective C?**

```
/**
 * If a message was compressed as a PNG image (a compression hack since
 * gzipping over WebSockets * is not supported yet), this function places the
 * "image" in a canvas element then decodes the * "image" as a Base64 string.
 *
 * @param data - object containing the PNG data.
 * @param callback - function with params:
 *   * data - the uncompressed data
 */
function decompressPng(data, callback) {
  // Uncompresses the data before sending it through (use image/canvas to do so).
  var image = new Image();
  // When the image loads, extracts the raw data (JSON message).
  image.onload = function() {
    // Creates a local canvas to draw on.
    var canvas = new Canvas();
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Sets width and height.
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;

    // Puts the data into the image.
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    // Grabs the raw, uncompressed data.
    var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height).data;

    // Constructs the JSON.
    var jsonData = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < imageData.length; i += 4) {
      // RGB
      jsonData += String.fromCharCode(imageData[i], imageData[i + 1], imageData[i + 2]);
    }
    callback(JSON.parse(jsonData));
  };
  // Sends the image data to load.
  image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data.data;
}
```

Comment: Your data is a raw PNG not JSON. Other than the first few 0's you have a PNG header `{ 0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A }`

Comment: Ok, so there must be something wrong in the step where I make `NSString *decodedString` since I am only seeing the header. `NSData * decodedData` should contain the compressed PNG data. How would I go about decompressing it to a string?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no.. I continued without compression, which, of course, meant sending larger amount of data is really slow.